# Periodic boundary conditions for Keras loss

Tags: keras, neural-network, regression, conv-neural-network, boundary

I try to predict values in the range 0-63. My metrics is MAE. If I use usual MAE as loss, CNN mixes the values like 0 and 63 as it's the edge.

I try to use my custom loss:

```
def cyclic_loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    loss = K.mean(K.square((y_true +image_height/2 - y_pred) % image_height-image_height/2))
    return loss
```

but get the MAE like this plot:

[image: plot]

How can I indicate CNN "*If you get value = 64 it means 1, not 64*"?

Comment: Do you mean your y_pred can have values from 0 to let's say infinity, but you want something like e.g. 64 mapped to 1, 70 mapped to 7 and 255 mapped to 0?

Comment: @fedor-petrov Yes, right

Comment: Just curious, what's the application? Are the values float or int? If int why not a classifier with 64 output neurons, and the value is chosen based on the neuron with the highest score?

But anyway you can try to replace ````y_pred```` with ````y_pred%64```` in your loss function.

Comment: That's a prediction of regression by image dataset, I have the dataset of images and one coordinate of object, but CNN has a problem to detect the object on the edges of image, and when object has coordinates 0 or 63, CNN confuses these values